# Protecting a workbook except for a few cells

Tags: vba, excel, password-protection

I am trying to protect my workbook but leave a few cells unprotected for user inputs. The code I am trying is as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("User Inputs").Range("D6:D12").Locked = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Protect Password = Password
Next ws

End Sub
```

When I run this, I get an error that says it is unable to set the locked property of the range class. How can I fix this?
Also, when I try to set a password manually and then try to unprotect with a macro, it says the password is incorrect, even if I have entered it. Do you know why this might be?

Thanks! I really appreciate any help!

Comment: I was going to add to my answer but I did not have the vba code on my phone - and as the point about un-checking cells was down-voted...

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` then you would see that you cannot write `ws.Protect Password := Password`.

Answer (score 2):

When you are explicitly giving the parameter by name, you should use the `:=` operator:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("User Inputs").Range("D6:D12").Locked = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
         ws.Protect Password := "SomePassword"
    Next ws

End Sub
```

As an alternative, simply write `ws.Protect  "SomePassword"`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know how to fix the problem of unlocking specific cells in VBA?