# Export Access queries to password-protected Excel workbook

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, export-to-excel, password-protection

I'm attempting to export 2 queries from an Access database to 2 tabs in an Excel workbook.  I want that workbook to be password-protected.  I'm having difficulty making it password protected in VBA.  Here's my VBA so far:

```
 Public Function ExportToExcel()



Call DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet(TransferType:=acExport, _
                                   TableName:="q1_Get_Load_Data", _
                                   FileName:="C:\Users\...\POPs_Reports.xlsx")
Call DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet(TransferType:=acExport, _
                                   TableName:="q2_Number_by_Alpha", _
                                   FileName:="C:\Users\...\POPs_Reports.xlsx")


End Function
```

Is there a way to add code to make the workbook password protected?

Comment: A search on here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/51617702/4961700

Comment: Hm, I still cannot get it to work with the example provided in that thread.

Comment: Would vba code help that protects sheets work instead?

Comment: That could work

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to protect 40 sheets in 6 different workbooks:

```
Sub protectAll()
Dim myCount
Dim i
myCount = Application.Sheets.Count
Sheets(1).Select
For i = 1 To myCount
    ActiveSheet.Protect "the_password", True, True
    If i = myCount Then
        End
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Next.Select
Next i
```

End Sub
Sub UnprotectAll()
    Dim myCount
    Dim i
    myCount = Application.Sheets.Count
    Sheets(1).Select
    For i = 1 To myCount
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect "the_password"
        If i = myCount Then
            End
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    Next i
End Sub

So, for the cells you want access to i.e. not protected then select the cell (or cells) and go to format cells and un-tick the "locked" checkbox,  (test it on a spare sheet!) see :

[image]

To not protect one sheet - have it at position 1 and start the loop at 2...

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work for my purposes- I just want the single Excel workbook (2 worksheets) in the original VBA to be password protected.  When I ran the ProtectAll sub after running the code that exports the queries to Excel, the worksheets were not password protected.