# Macro Protection in all Worksheets but only for cells with some value

Tags: excel, vba

i need some help to make my code work. My code is pretty simple. It goes through all my worksheets and make simple check in Columns A:D. If one cell has some text it will be locked. All free cells will stay for users unlocked.

It starts with other macros from my worksheet with Workbook_Open as Call command.

I used it all the time in each Worksheet separatly, but it won't work with new sheets so i decided to make it somehow global and dynamic for old sheets and new added sheets.

Old code:

```
Public Sub auo_open()

Dim strPassword As String
strPassword = "Athens"

With Tabelle1
    .Unprotect Password:=strPassword
    .Cells.Locked = True

    On Error Resume Next
    .Range("A:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Protect Password:=strPassword, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True

End With
Exit Sub
```

As you see it wasn't that good i had to put for each sheet a call command

new Code:

```
Public Sub Protection()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim strPassword As String
 strPassword = "Athens"


For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    ws.Unprotect Password:=strPassword
    ws.Cells.Locked = True

    On Error Resume Next
    ws.Range("A:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False
    On Error GoTo 0
    ws.Protect Password:=strPassword, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at how I protect sheets: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51661932/4961700 -it may help...

Comment: No need to loop. Use the `Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` to lock the cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to my comment above, try something like this. This code will automatically be applicable to the newly added worksheets

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim strPassword As String: strPassword = "Athens"
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A:D")) Is Nothing Then
        With Sh
            .Unprotect strPassword
            Cells.Locked = True
            Range("A:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False
            .Protect strPassword
        End With
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

**Screenshots**

Put the code in the `ThisWorkbook` code area.

[image]

Comment: So it's good but if you write somethign wrong it will be blocked anyway. My code blocked new things after new start from the Excel file. It checked all cells that were filled and blocked them. I need it to be blocked firstly when the work is done

Comment: Your command blocks each cell that was edited without time to make some corrections. My code checked cells after restart. so till that restart they were able to make changes to lately edited cells but not those that were checked and blocked by restart

Comment: In that case you will have to run a code from a module which loops though all sheets and locks it using `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`

Comment: Like i did in new code? It is broken. It loops only few Columns and cells and it seems random. Ex. Table 1 A1:D10, Table 2 A1:B4. It should check all cells in Range A:D

Comment: Your new code works for me. It is not random... `.Range("A:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` takes care of it

Comment: I need to be more precise. If i start it, it blocks all cells that have some values and other ones that are beyond last modified cell without values. Example: I wrote something in C14. Used my macro. All Cells empty cells in range to C14 are unprotected, only C14. But all beyond that cell are blocked aswell. It shouldn't work in that way. Whole Column D says protected and all Cells below Cell 14.

Comment: That is because you are using `.Range("A:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`. You should find the last row in all 4 columns one by one and then lock them :)

Comment: ah ok Thx:-) You're right. I will fix it in free time